# Add method to frame.add()

Tags: java, swing, exception

I want to load the method `mainWindow()` in `frame.add()`. However, I get the exception:

`mainWindow cannot be resolved to a type` because it is not from the type component.

```
public class MainWindow {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class);

    public void mainWindow() {

        log.info("enter mainWindow method");

        MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("fillx", "[right]rel[grow,fill]", "[]10[]");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);

        panel.add(new JLabel("Enter size:"),"");
        panel.add(new JTextField(""),"wrap");
        panel.add(new JLabel("Enter weight:"),"");
        panel.add(new JTextField(""),"");

    }

    public void createAndShowGUI() {

        log.info("create and show GUI");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FileChooserDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Add content to the window.
        frame.add(new mainWindow());

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }


}
```

Is there another way to add the `mainWindow()` method to `frame.add()`, without changing it into a component?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: You cannot add or `load` mehtods in Java. This is not functional language. Might be you need to wait till java 8.

Comment: There is no such thing a "loading a method" in the Java language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
public void mainWindow() {

    log.info("enter mainWindow method");

    MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("fillx", "[right]rel[grow,fill]", "[]10[]");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);

    panel.add(new JLabel("Enter size:"),"");
    panel.add(new JTextField(""),"wrap");
    panel.add(new JLabel("Enter weight:"),"");
    panel.add(new JTextField(""),"");

}
```

Into:

```
public JComponent mainWindow() {

    log.info("enter mainWindow method");

    MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("fillx", "[right]rel[grow,fill]", "[]10[]");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);

    panel.add(new JLabel("Enter size:"),"");
    panel.add(new JTextField(""),"wrap");
    panel.add(new JLabel("Enter weight:"),"");
    panel.add(new JTextField(""),"");

    return panel;
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. Do I have any real advantages when using a `JComponent`? Or would it be better to change the system, how the gui loads?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "how the gui loads". With the change I'm suggesting, your code becomes pretty standard Swing code.